# How to write about a group of friends who were all female

Tags: gender, grammatical-number, past-participle, past

The sentence I am trying to write is

> I wanted to go to London with my friends.

All the friends are female.

So far I have

> Ich habe mit ____ _________ (my friends) nach London gehen gewollt.

I don't know if that is right but my answer is for school. So it has to be in the *ich habe ... gewollt* format.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, you probably should look up the translation, and then how to decline the word.  Unfortunately we don't solve homeworks.

Comment: @c.p. I think i must have misunderstood the use of this website, I'm not asking it to answer exercises for me, I'm asking for help with an essay, for speaking the language? I don't understand how you would write the plural or how you would make Freunden female

Comment: Some dictionaries give it to you: https://www.dict.cc/?s=friend

Comment: Better: Ich wollte mit meinen Freundinnen nach London fahren. Freundinnen is a group of female friends. Freunde may be only male but also female and male.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich habe mit ____ _________ (my friends) nach London gehen gewollt.

isn't standard German. You have to use an **Ersatzinfinitiv** here:

> Ich habe mit ____ _________ (my friends) nach London gehen **wollen**.

---

There is no way to make a word "female". Instead, words for people and nearly all occupations exist in a general and in a female-only version. Most times, the difference is only an added *-in*:

```
both genders    female only
---------------------------
Freund          Freundin
Partner         Partnerin
Lehrer          Lehrerin
Helfer          Helferin
Bäcker          Bäckerin
Schneider       Schneiderin
Chef            Chefin
…
```

The plural of those "female only" forms is constructed by adding *-nen*.

For occupations with *-mann*, there is another word with *-frau*.

```
male only        female only
------------------------------
Obmann           Obfrau
Amtmann          Amtsfrau (note the Fugen-s)
Feuerwehrmann    Feuerwehrfrau
…
```

The plural of those "female only" forms is constructed by adding *-en*.

And finally, there is a small number of irregular words:

```
male only                        female only
---------------------------------------------------------------
Prinz, pl.: Prinzen              Prinzessin, pl.: Prinzessinnen
Anwalt, pl.: Anwälte             Anwältin, pl.: Anwältinnen
Beauftragter, pl.: Beauftragte   Beauftragte, pl.: Beauftragte
…
```

None of those lists are exhaustive. Consult your dictionary.

Comment: It is not good German. A native speaker would say: Ich wollte mit meinen Freunden nach London fahren. In English you can go by train, but in German going means using your feet and legs, not a train. Other possibilities: Ich wollte mit meinen Freunden nach London reisen (oder auch fliegen)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment on the question?

Comment: @Uwe: Wenn jemand dauerhaft fort*geht* kann man durchaus auch das Verb *gehen* verwenden: »Werner wohnt nicht mehr hier. Er ist vor fünf Jahren nach London gegangen.« Da ist es nämlich egal, ob er mit dem Bus oder mit dem Flugzeug gereist ist. Die damalige Reise spielt heute keine Rolle mehr. Wichtig ist nur mehr die Tatsache, dass Werner jetzt dauerhaft wo anders ist.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast : ich weiß. Man kann auch sagen "Ich gehe nach London" wenn man für einige Jahre dort bleiben will. Das geht auch wenn die Abreise unmittelbar bevorsteht.

Comment: Die Anwaltskammer ist also eine Organisation nur für Männer? Freund, Partner usw. sind nicht nur Wörter für beide Geschlechter, sondern gerade auch für Funktionen unbeachtlich des Geschlechts. Auch fehlt mir die Zuordnung von Gast, Person und Mitglied in der Liste.